# Sanity Client - TypeError: Object is not a function in defineHttpRequest

Tags: reactjs, sanity

I'm trying to setup a connection with Sanity with my local build, however I'm getting the following error when configuring my client.js file.

`TypeError: Object is not a function. (In 'Object(get_it_middleware__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_14__["retry"])', 'Object' is an instance of Object)`

**client.js**

```
import { createClient } from "@sanity/client";

const client = createClient ({
  projectId: 'xxx-xxx-xxx',
  dataset: 'production',
  apiVersion: '2023-07-28',
  token: '',
  useCdn: true, 
})

export default client;
```

**defineHttpRequest**
*node_modules/@sanity/client/dist/index.browser.js:141*

```
  138 | var _ref$maxRetries = _ref.maxRetries,
  139 |   maxRetries = _ref$maxRetries === void 0 ? 5 : _ref$maxRetries,
  140 |   retryDelay = _ref.retryDelay;
> 141 | var request = getIt([maxRetries > 0 ? retry({
      | ^  142 |   // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  143 |   retryDelay: retryDelay,
  144 |   // This option is typed incorrectly in get-it.
```

I've tried reinstalling "@sanity/client" as well as previous versions, however the error still continues.